# numpy array divide column by vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3x3 numpy array and I want to divide each column of this with a vector 3x1. I know how to divide each row by elements of the vector, but am unable to find a solution to divide each column.

Answer (score 8):

You can transpose your array to divide on each column

```
(arr_3x3.T/arr_3x1).T
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try several things:

```
In [347]: A=np.arange(9.).reshape(3,3)
In [348]: A
Out[348]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])

In [349]: x=10**np.arange(3).reshape(3,1)

In [350]: A/x
Out[350]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  1.  ,  2.  ],
       [ 0.3 ,  0.4 ,  0.5 ],
       [ 0.06,  0.07,  0.08]])
```

So this has divided each row by a different value

```
In [351]: A/x.T
Out[351]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  0.1 ,  0.02],
       [ 3.  ,  0.4 ,  0.05],
       [ 6.  ,  0.7 ,  0.08]])
```

And this has divided each column by a different value

`(3,3)` divided by `(3,1)` => replicates `x` across columns.

With the transpose `(1,3)` array is replicated across rows.

It's important that `x` be 2d when using `.T` (transpose).  A `(3,)` array transposes to a `(3,)` array - that is, no change.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest seems to be

```
A = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
b=np.arange(1,4)
A/b
```

A will be

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

and b will be

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

and the division will produce

```
array([[1. , 1. , 1. ],
       [4. , 2.5, 2. ],
       [7. , 4. , 3. ]])
```

The first column is divided by `1`, the second column by `2`, and the third by `3`.
If I've misinterpreted your columns for rows, simply transform with .T - as C_Z_ answered above.